# Add views to fragment programatically and load them only when they are visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am building this app, where I have a parrent activity, and like 6 fragments so far, with swipeable tabs, and in every fragment there are programatically added text views and few image views, and what I want to do is, I am looking for a way to load the stuff only when the fragment is visible, I checked with the debugger and noticed that it calls `public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {` very early, and I thought I could do it in that method. The problem is it's crashing as soon as it starts loading the views, so how can I fix it? The problem could be related to getting the right context of the views, not sure, here's my fragment:

```
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class Fragment10 extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout layout;
    ImageView iv;
    String someUrl;
    ArrayList<CharInfo> ci;

    public Fragment10() {
        // Empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment10, container, false);
        layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Bundle b = this.getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        ci = b.getParcelableArrayList("stuff");
        someUrl = b.getString("someUrl");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (menuVisible) {

            // View v = new View(getActivity());

            TextView tv;

            tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setText(ci.get(0).name);
            layout.addView(tv);

            tv = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(ci.get(0).surname));
            layout.addView(tv);


            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
            String imgUrl = "http://" + someUrl + "someUrl.here" + regionUrl + "/" + ci.get(0).pic;
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrl, iv);
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice I am using an external library for the image view.
and these are the errors I am getting

```
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:318)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3236)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3281)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:583)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:578)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:574)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.stanga.wowarmory.Fragment1.setMenuVisibility(Fragment1.java:50)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:129)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-23 08:12:19.977: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 08:12:23.317: I/Process(849): Sending signal. PID: 849 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Generally you do the getViews/findviewbyid in the onCreateView method. Then in the onViewCreated you do the setAdapter... all stuff that needed the views to be there. And in onActivity created you can do stuff that need the activity to be initialized like the method GetActivity(). Stuff like bundle/argument you pass to the fragment can be in the onCreate method.

Comment: but can I do these things in the setMenuVisibility method?

Comment: You can of course you do what you want ;) but if i were you i wouldn't. Two reason : First the GetActivity() in that method could crash the application, second if you are the one calling that method to hide/show this will work out somehow but else it won't work well because you won't be able to control what is happenning to your ui ^^"

Comment: if not getActivity what then?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            //Do your code which you did in setMenuVisibility() method
        }
    }
```